# Efficient Testing of Python Structural Pattern Matching

Tags: pytest, pattern-matching, python-3.10

I am building a command line interface using python 3.10. The `save` command, calls different functions based on the option passed. Let's say possible options are `"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"`.

Using structural pattern matching in python 3.10 I have code similar to the following:

```
# __main__.py

from my_module import func_A, func_B, func_C, func_D, func_E, get_from_cache

@cli.command()
def save(option):
    match option:
        case "A":
            to_save = func_A()
        case "B":
            to_save = func_B()
        case "C":
            to_save = func_C()
        case "D":
            to_save = func_D()
        case "E":
            to_save = func_E()
        case None:
            to_save = get_from_cache()
        case _:
            print("Not an Option")
            return

    # rest of save command
```

I have written tests for each function separately. However, Pytest Coverage reports that the pattern matching statements are missing in the `__main__.py` file. Is there a pythonic (efficient) way to test that passing a given option results in the correct function being called?

The only solution I can think of would be to mock each function and write a test for options A-E. Then as options increase, I would have to add a new mock and new test.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. I can actually use parametrization and mocking. Since the mocking is just strings, I just concatenated the appropriate string and used the built-in typer test runner.

```
from unittest import mock
import pytest



@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "func, option",
    [
        ("func_A", "A"),
        ("func_B", "B"),
        ("func_C", "C"),
        ("func_D", "D"),
        ("func_E", "E"),
        ("get_from_cache", None),
    ],
)
def test_matching(func, option):
    with mock.patch("src.__main__." + func) as save_mock:
        runner.invoke(cli, ["save", "--option", option])
        save_mock.assert_called_once()
```